# When did the 5 other evils got into the soul stone? And how?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm not that big on knowledge of Diablo, but how in the hell did the 5 first evils got into the black soulstone?

And since we are on the topic, after that the 7 devils were trapped into it, Leah had to user her magic 24/7 to keep them in there... so how didn't the soulstone blow up during the entire years it was without surveillance in Kulle's lair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are told this in-game upon collecting the black soulstone ([Source](http://d3db.com/quest/i/the-black-soulstone/31)):

> BARBARIAN: Five Lords of Hell now reside within this stone. This was
>   your doing, Adria!
>
> ADRIA: Twenty years ago, during the Darkening of Tristram, Cain told me
>   of Zoltun Kulle's profane soulstone.
>
> LEAH: That's why you left me... You went to mark the demons' souls, so
>   that they could be drawn into Kulle's vessel!
>
> ADRIA: Yes, my daughter. I have sacrificed everything for this...

The other classes only differ in what they say when they discover it.

Answer (score 2):

I swear I answered this some where but from what I recall the souls do not enter the stone until you complete the stone again during THIS play through. Adria was going around marking the souls to make sure they would end up in the black soulstone, but they only got there when the stone was completed during act 2.

Answer (score 2):

Leah's mother actually "marked" the other evils. So when their soulstones were destroyed their souls were pulled into the black soulstone.
So in fact the other evils weren't for that long of a time in the black soulstone. This is said in the dialog after you killed Zoltan Kulle.

Also since there only five of them in there, the stress on the stone wasn't as high. (Zoltan designed it to hold all seven evils...)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, the 5 demon's souls were marked by Adria during the previous 20 years, so when the Black Soulstone is completed, it sucks them into it immediatly (from memory, you see something fly into the stone during the scene?).

It did not blow up earlier because the souls were not in it until Kulle finishes it in front of the player. It was previously just an empty, inactive, unfinished soulstone.